# Why shouldn't acceptance of an answer count towards a tag's score?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

When you vote a question or an answer, the votes contribute towards [the tag score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92699/can-someone-explain-how-the-tag-points-work).

It would seem to be that if an answer is marked as the answer, that says more about the the poster's strength in the area than an answer not marked as the answer. While this is accounted for in rep(via an additional +2 rep), why is it not accounted for in the tags? (Something like a +1 for the tags that the question has in addition to the amount of upvotes the answer has)?

I think that it is important to count how many times a user's answer has been accepted in a tag category, in addition to how many upvotes they got. Seems like a good idea to treat the answer checkmark as an increment to score in this regard.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. What do you mean by "count towards tags"? Are you asking if answers count toward tag badges, or if answers count to the number of posts indicated for a tag?

Comment: I am asking why, if an post is marked as the answer, it should not count towards the tags more. I.e. if an answer is posted with 2 upvotes, and it's marked as the answer, then the tags get +2, same as if it was not marked as the answer. It would seem that it should count more if it was marked as the answer.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I can't tell you a specific reason. If you think that should be the case, you can retag your question to be a feature-request and explain why you think it ought to be implemented that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112624/shouldnt-an-accepted-answer-count-towards-the-teacher-badge/112693#112693) quite nicely explains why. Although the answer relates to the Teacher badge, it can be applied to tag scores:

> Having a score of "1 or more" is a validation from the community that
>   the answer was voted by the majority as "useful." That's to avoid
>   awarding the badge for trivial or wrong answers.
>
> The accepted answer function doesn't have that check. It is only the
>   opinion of one person. If the answer was down-voted by the community
>   at large, the original author should not be able to overrule simply by
>   accepting the answer (awarding the Teacher badge).
>
> Up-voting and accepting an answer serve two different purposes.
>   Ideally, if the author saw fit to accept the answer, they should have
>   up-voted. But ultimately voting a question as "useful" is a function
>   of the *community* vote.

Answer (score 0):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), as [@sblair quotes](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3719/6574):

> ...The accepted answer function doesn't have that check. *It is only the opinion of one person...*

If this question was treated *strictly* as a feature request, it would be tagged [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) instead.